# Non-linear recurrence relation $T(n)=nT^2\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)$ with $T(1)=6$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I am concerned to solve the recurrence relation $T(n)=nT^2\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)$ with initial condition $T(1)=6$.

I have tried to do some transformation like $N=2^k$ and some other things like that but all of them was meaningless.

Comment: I don't know how to get the answer but the answer is here. :) http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=T%28n%29%3D%28T%28n%2F2%29%29%5E2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As usual, this only defines $T$ on the powers of $2$ hence consider 
$$
t_k=2^kT(2^k).
$$
Then $t_k=4t_{k-1}^2$ for every $k\geqslant1$. Iterating, one gets
$$
t_k=4\cdot4^2\cdots4^{2^{k-1}}\cdot (t_0)^{2^k},
$$
that is,
$$
2^k\cdot T(2^k)=4^{2^k-1}\cdot T(1)^{2^k},
$$
or
$$
T(\color{red}{2^k})=\frac{(4T(1))^{\color{red}{2^k}}}{4\cdot\color{red}{2^k}}.
$$
If one wants to extend this to every $n$ (which is not a consequence of the hypothesis), probably the most natural formula is
$$
T(\color{blue}{n})=\frac{(4T(1))^\color{blue}{n}}{4\cdot\color{blue}{n}}.
$$